# remove the first two part of delimited string

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a string with delimiter '_', example below

'AAA_BBB_CCC_DDD_EEE'

I want to trim the first two elements of delimited string. Expected output:

'CCC_DDD_EEE'

Comment: Would you like to achieve this using SQL only?

Comment: Yes, specifically in Redshift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use `regexp_substr()`:

```
select regexp_substr(string, '^[^_]+_[^_]+_(.*)$', 1, 1, 'e')
```

Or `regexp_replace()`:

```
select regexp_replace(string, ''^[^_]+_[^_]+_', '')
```